# gulp-include with gulp-uglify doesn't work

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I have a `gulp.task 'scripts'` that uses `gulp-uglify`. Then I also added `gulp-import` and it didn't work. If i do only `uglify` it works. If I do only `import` it works. But if i do both at the same time it doesn't work.
Here is the function:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src([
            'testgulp/**/*.js', '!testgulp/**/_*.js', '!testgulp/**/*.min.js'
        ])
        .pipe(include()) //if I comment only this line, uglify works
            .on('error', console.log)
        .pipe(uglify()) //if I comment only this line, include works
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file) { return file.base; }));

});
```

And then on terminal I have this response when try to do both:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/personal-sandrina-p/_main/v3/node_modules/map-stream/index.js:103
        throw err
        ^
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
    at createError (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/personal-sandrina-p/_main/v3/node_modules/gulp-uglify/lib/create-error.js:6:14)
    at wrapper (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/personal-sandrina-p/_main/v3/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/lodash/_createHybrid.js:87:15)
    at trycatch (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/personal-sandrina-p/_main/v3/node_modules/gulp-uglify/minifier.js:26:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.minify [as _transform] (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/personal-sandrina-p/_main/v3/node_modules/gulp-uglify/minifier.js:76:19)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/personal-sandrina-p/_main/v3/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:159:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/personal-sandrina-p/_main/v3/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:147:83)
    at doWrite (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/personal-sandrina-p/_main/v3/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:313:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/personal-sandrina-p/_main/v3/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:302:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/personal-sandrina-p/_main/v3/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:241:11)
    at Stream.ondata (stream.js:31:26)
```

I'm moving away from Koala App and the append/prepend feature was awesome, so i would like to do the same with Gulp. I tried gulp-include and gulp-import, both has the same problem. What i'm doing wrong? 
Thank you :)

**-EDIT-**
i also tried gulp-sync and hardcode a timeout() on minifyit task, but doesn't fix the problem...

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I think I found the problem.
First of all I needed to install gulp-util to find out better what was the error.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src([
            'assets/scripts/**/*.js',
            '!assets/scripts/**/_*.js',
            '!assets/scripts/**/*.min.js'
        ])
        .pipe(include())
            .on('error', console.log)
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', gutil.log)) //gulp-util
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file) { return file.base; }));
});
```

Then it was something with ES5 shorthand uglify that trows an error. I had to install gulp-babel as well, and the final code:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src([
            'assets/scripts/**/*.js',
            '!assets/scripts/**/_*.js',
            '!assets/scripts/**/*.min.js'
        ])
        .pipe(include())
            .on('error', console.log)
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015'], //this fixed a shorthand javascript error
            compact: true
        }))
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', gutil.log)) // gulp-util
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
});
```

And that fixed my problem.
Hope to help someone else :)

Comment: gulp-util helped me find the error (pump didn't), thanks for sharing!

Comment: gulp-util seems to be deprecated? Any alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should use pump module.

```
   var pump = require('pump');

   gulp.task('scripts', function(){
       pump([
          gulp.src([...]),
          ugilfy(),
          rename({ suffix: '.min' }),
          gulp.dest(...)
       ]);
   });
```

And you can see [why use pump](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/blob/master/docs/why-use-pump/README.md#why-use-pump)

Comment: what is the difference between pump and util ?

Answer (score 0):

Just have them as separate functions and have the include one run before the uglify one:

```
 gulp.task('include,function({
       // include code here
 });

 gulp.task('uglify',['include'],function({
          // uglify code here
 });
```

the include function between the [] will run before the uglify function when you run the uglify function

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't fixed. the problem was with a shorthand on javascript i used... check my own answer above for more details